# Making a simple ajax post in jQuery and Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a Ruby on Rails post via AJAX, and can't figure it out. So close!

**HTML:**

```
= link_to image_tag(current_user.votes.any? {|v| v.votable_id == post.id && v.value > 0} ? 'vote-up-selected.jpg' : 'vote-up.jpg'), vote_up_post_path(post)
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
def vote_up
  get_vote
  @vote.value += 1 unless @vote.value == 1
  @vote.save
  respond_to do |format|
    #format.html { render :action => 'vote_up', , :notice => "Voted Up." ) }
  end
end
```

Sorry, this is a dumb question. I'm more so asking as to what the 'best' practice to doing this is.

Comment: No error. I can get this to work just fine if it renders an entire page, or even redirects back to its original page after submit. The trick, I guess, is just getting into to send a POST request without reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`route_name_path` isn't gonna return 'post' link, even if `route_name` is specified with post requirement. However, `link_to` method does take `:method` option. I never used, but they claim it creates hidden form to submit request with passed http verb:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002142

But switching to get might be easier: at least, you won't have to mess with [authenticity_token](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#request-forgery-protection). (not sure if it's generated by default with that form)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out Ryan's railscast about using jQuery with Rails:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Comment: Thank you FD, that was very informitive.